# Handle MySQL exceptions in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, mysql

The following code checks if I can connect to the MySQL database or not. It is working fine when it connects but when it can't connect it throws out an error instead of executing the 'Else' statement

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace MySQLConnection
{
    public partial class FrmConnection : Form
    {
        public FrmConnection()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string connectionString = "host=192.168.0.91; database=c#1; user=test1; password=test1";
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection con= new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                if(con.State==ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    label1.Text = "Connection Established!";
                }
                else
                {
                    label1.Text = "Connection Error!";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error

> An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Additional information: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle exceptions, you can do this:

```
using (MySqlConnection con= new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            label1.Text = "Connection Established!";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            label1.Text = "Connection Error!\n"+ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

It's pretty explained: It will `try` to open the connection and set a success message.
If it fails, it will say that the connection failed and display the error message from the `catched` exception.
Then, on the `finally` block, it will close the connection, after both `try` and `catch` has finished executing.

I'm not sure but since you're using `using`, you wouldn't need the finally block, for the `using` function will close the connection automatically.

More info on the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz(v=vs.80).aspx) for the `try catch finally` blocks.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly. I just started learning C# and this try catch method will really help me alot in the future. Cheers

Comment: C# is a really nice language, I hope you will enjoy it :)